# (С#) Проблема с System.Net.HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

Допустим, у меня есть такой код

```
void doAction(string link){
HttpWebRequest r=(HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
r.GetResponse();
}
```

так вот, после двух-трех вызовов этой функции все запросы становятся бесконечными (выполняются очень долго без получения ответа). Что я делаю не так?
У меня MS.Net 4.5
Причем, если использовать WebClient, то все нормально, но там как я понимаю, нельзя использовать Method=HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Метод [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx) возвращает объект типа [`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx), который инкапсулирует в себе ответ и реализует интерфейс [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable.aspx). По всем правилам, после прочтения ответа, нужно вызвать метод `Close()` или `Dispose()` у объекта `WebResponse`. Приведенный вами код нужно немножко доработать:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
var response = request.GetResponse();
// Работа с ответом ...
response.Close();
```

---

**2)** Если использовать WebClient, то HTTP-метод для запроса задать не получится. Однако можно расширить этот класс, переопределив метод [`GetWebRequest(Uri address)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx). Можно сделать например так:

```
public class HeadMethodWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Или более универсально: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268926/head-with-webclient#12862590)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: `using` для этого есть, а не Close вызывать.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link))
```

Comment: Стоило бы ещё упомянуть про то, почему это решает проблему :)

Comment: @PashaPash, я в каком-то другом ответе уже писал, но искать пока лень. Надо бы ссылку добавить.